# jquery history back button to reset

Tags: jquery, reset, history, back

I am having a problem with my website. I have some animations when a redirect is happening to get a transition effect from page to page. The problem is that if a user clicks the Browsers Back button it goes to the previous page but it does not reset the animations so everything stays hidden as when you exited the page.

To have a demo of the error go to http://www.econtentsys.gr/affiliate/xenosk/temp/amigdalos/main.php , Click on About Me and then click on your browsers (history) Back button.

Is there anyway to reset the pages cache lets say every time the page gets showed so the transitions will always work ?

Only Google Chrome functions properly on me. All the other browsers are having the same error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Browser "Back" Button vs. jQuery-animated page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6215943/browser-back-button-vs-jquery-animated-page)

Comment: More duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3628459/ http://stackoverflow.com/q/1195440/ http://stackoverflow.com/q/158319/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your animation doesn't reset when you click the back button because the page is cached in the [bfcache (Back-Forward Cache)](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_Firefox_1.5_caching).

The linked article mentions several situations where bfcache is not used, one being when the `unload` handler is uses. Therefore, the simplest approach would be to simple add an empty `onunload` attribute to your `<body>` tag, i.e.

```
<body onunload="">
```

p.s. I've only tested this in Firefox.

Comment: It seems to do the trick. Thank you very much for the quick reply Shawn!